# get the path of WebService.asmx.cs file from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have two projects in ASP.NET WebForms named TestServices and TestApp.

```
TestApp
  -TestServices
  --App_Code
  ---WebServoce1.asmx.cs

  -TestApp
  --MyServices
  ---WebServoce1.asmx
```

I want to get the path of WebServoce.asmx.cs

Content of WebServoce.asmx file:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="" Class="TestServices.App_Code.WebServoce1" %>
```

I want to get the path of WebServoce.asmx.cs from TestServices project and to set the path inside Code behind of 
WebServoce1.asmx file
How can I do this ?

Thank you to all!

Comment: What do you mean by " set the path inside Code behind of WebServoce1.asmx". Do you want to move file?

Comment: I want to get the path of WebServoce1.asmx.cs file and to  this patth inside codebehind=" The path of Websevoce1.asmx" directive

Comment: this doesn't make a lot of sense. You want dynamically set the code behind of `WebServoce1.asmx` from the code behind of `WebServoce1.asmx`?  `WebServoce.asmx.cs` is the code behind file and I don't think you can access files from a separate project anyways. It honestly sounds like you have a very bad setup

Comment: Why do you have them in separate projects?